# Ruby Parsing: Error when I trying to put Cyrillic symbols into URL request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, parsing, cyrillic

I wrote a Bot for Telegram, where users can receive images for their requests. But there was one problem, which I could not solve.

Some example with parsing on Ruby:

```
json_object = JSON.parse(open("https://api.site.com/search/photos?query=" + message.text + "&per_page=10&client_id=42324d2lkedi234fs342dfse2c038fdfsdfs").read)
```

`message.text` - It's a field with request from users.

Everything works fine with latin literals, but when I send Cyrillic(API also supports Cyrillic alphabet) symbols I get the below error:

> /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:21:in
>   `split': URI must be ascii only
>   "https://api.site.com/search/photos?query=\u0432\u0430\u0432\u0430&per_page=10&client_id=42324d2lkedi234fs342dfse2c038fdfsdfs"
>   (URI::InvalidURIError)

I used Encoding with utf-8 and win-1252, but nothing helped. How should this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your cyrillic string:

```
URI.encode('http://google.com?1=АБВ') # => "%D0%90%D0%91%D0%92"
```

So, use it like this (or encode whole url):

```
URI.encode(message.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
"anything".parameterize.underscore.humanize.downcase
```